# Which technlogy sqlnavigator uses for excecute commands?

Tags: sql, oracle, installation, windows-installer, sqlplus

I'm tryng to excecute an sql script through sqlplus, but the result it's different from excecuting it through SqlNavigator, how can I run this script as it's launched from SqlNavigator? I need this for a Custom Action inside an installer.

I get a lot of `SP2-0734` executing under sqlplus.

Code is here https://pastebin.com/MgYd2bE0

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code (in text form).  If all the code is on an external site, this question will become useless for others once that external site purges your content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found soulution. 
SqlPlus assumes the blank line means a new statement starts here. 
I removed all the blank lines form the script and all just go fine.